# migrate multiple java dependent projects from eclipse to intellij

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea, intellij-13

I would like to know how can I migrate my eclipse projects into IntelliJ.

I already imported them in IntelliJ but I have no idea on how to include one inside another.

In eclipse, Project Properties, Java Build Path I could've add another project as a dependency. How can I do the same thing in IntelliJ?

Comment: Why aren't  you using one tool on dependencies managment like [maven](http://maven.apache.org/), this allows to you to make the project indipendent from your ide

Comment: I cannot use Maven in this project.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [this](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/documentation/migration_faq.html) you might find what you are looking for.

Comment: It is helpful but it didn't solved my problem. I knew those differences but I couldn't make one project see another one even if I added it to the module dependency.

Answer (score 1):

Doing this manually is a pain, but you have said you can't use a tool like `maven` or `gradle`, so it's just to set it up like this:

Go into project structure (ctrl-alt-shift-s) and select `Modules` on the left side.

For each module, you can then set up dependencies on other modules or libraries.

Good luck.

Comment: I already tried that. I've seen that in the project I have dependencies on some generated classes so I need to include the target classes. I don't know why it is not including them...